# V8 - Exposing a non-void C++ function to the Javascript code

Tags: c++, binding, v8, function-templates

I have already successfully gotten V8 to run arbitrary Javascript files.  The trouble comes when I try to expose a C++ function so that it can be run by the Javascript code.

I define the following simple toy function,

```cpp
v8::Handle<v8::Value> f(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args)
{
    v8::Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
    v8::HandleScope scope(isolate);
    
    return v8::Number::New(isolate,2);
}
```

Then, I attempt to add it to a global object template as follows.

```cpp
        v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate> global = v8::ObjectTemplate::New(isolate);
            global->Set(isolate, "f",
                        v8::FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, f) );

        v8::Local<v8::Context> context = v8::Context::New(isolate, nullptr, global);
```

This exact pattern worked perfectly fine when `f` was a `void` function, but now that I ask for it to give a return value, I get the following error.

```
cisco/test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
cisco/test.cpp:52:61: error: invalid conversion from ‘v8::Handle<v8::Value> (*)(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&) {aka v8::Local<v8::Value> (*)(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&)}’ to ‘v8::FunctionCallback {aka void (*)(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&)}’ [-fpermissive]
                         v8::FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, f) );
                                                             ^
In file included from cisco/test.cpp:2:0:
./include/v8.h:6495:34: note:   initializing argument 2 of ‘static v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> v8::FunctionTemplate::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::FunctionCallback, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Signature>, int, v8::ConstructorBehavior, v8::SideEffectType, const v8::CFunction*, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t)’
   static Local<FunctionTemplate> New(
```

The [samples](https://github.com/v8/v8/tree/master/samples) from the V8 docs do not have any non-void examples.  In fact, I only know that the return type should be `Handle<Value>` because of [this](https://github.com/ruby0x1/v8-tutorials/blob/main/02%20expose%20functions/02%20expose%20functions.cpp) example from 2011.  It basically uses the same pattern I did to add the global function (I did try changing `Local<ObjectTemplate>` to `Handle<ObjectTemplate>`, but this didn't fix it), so I'm not sure why mine isn't working.

I'm somewhat at a loss for how to proceed.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-16.0/dd/d0d/classv8_1_1_function_callback_info.html

Return `void`.  Your `args` has a ReturnValue property.  You can set your return value into it.

```
args.GetReturnValue().Set( 2 );
```

I find google code tends to change APIs a lot, so looking at current docs and/or source is your best bet.

Comment: You're a godsend, thank you.  I wasn't able to find any explanations for how that worked anywhere, and the samples from the current docs didn't help either.

Do you have any recommendations for any projects with up-to-date V8 code that I can refer to as a sample?

Comment: @cisco Nope, I just googled some terms in your error messages and read the docs.  Have never touched v8 personally. Hard part was reading current, not decade old, docs.

Comment: That makes sense, I suppose my googling isn't so strong then.  https://v8.dev/docs/embed isn't a decade old, though, and still contained a frustrating lack of information.  Looking at decade-old samples on github probably wasn't the smartest idea, though.

But anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: Chrome code-search can help you out as well to find users of an existing API.
test-api.cc is the place where V8 dumps detailed tests: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:v8/test/cctest/test-api.cc

Comment: FWIW, I count 8 usages of `GetReturnValue().Set(...)` in the [V8 samples](https://github.com/v8/v8/tree/master/samples) you already linked to; https://v8.dev/docs/embed mentions it three times.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still pretty inexperienced haha.  I checked the samples in the docs after receiving this answer and realized that `GetReturnValue()` was in fact there.  The issue was that it never explicitly said what it did, so I wasn't able to recognize it as the thing that needed to be done for functions to have a return value.  Perhaps a more seasoned developer would have been able to infer it, but I would have liked v8.dev/docs/embed to explicitly say, "This is what you do..."  Oh well, you live and learn :)))